# A strange click during audio recordings

Tags: audio-recording

I have a strange problem when recording audio, with my HP Pavilion 15-ck030nl (Windows 10). Both if I record through an external microphone or through the microphone of a webcam (via USB), from the recording I can hear clicks every 0.28 seconds exactly. If I record through the internal microphone of the computer this problem does not occur.
What could I do about it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like pickup of RFI (radio frequency interference) along the mic or USB cable. Any nearby source of RF, such as a radar station, cell telephone tower, or even a cell phone in a pocket, can be picked up by the cable to the microphone. The cables are shielded (have one conductor inside another) to help prevent this, but there can be leakage.

Test if it's RFI by moving the laptop to a different place or by surrounding the laptop, mic cable and mic with a sheet of aluminum foil. If the noise gets softer (or louder), it's likely due to RFI.

[Ferrite beads](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=ferrite%20bead&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aferrite%20bead) on cables may help, but in extreme cases, e.g. near a powerful radar, you may need to make a [Faraday shield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) from copper screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your recording frequency.
Try toggling from 48k to 44.1k or vice versa & see if that helps. I've a suspicion it could be as simple as clock mismatch.